# IOS SQLite Returns NULL for special characters such as ö

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am having problems reading data from a SQLite database. The problem is with special characters such as 'ö'.

To create the query statement I use:

```
// create sql statement 
const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Table"] UTF8String];

// to read different rows
if ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)!=NULL){
string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,        0)];}
```

However, if there are any special accented characters - this results in the string output being NULL. Data is input to the SQLite database via a php script and then uploaded to the app via an URL request.  If standard characters are used without accents it works fine.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: Is it stringWithUTF8String: that fails? It will return nil if you use some other string-encoding. What is the output of sqlite3_column_text()?

Comment: The upload might be wrong. What is the output of `SELECT QUOTE(CAST(MyColumn AS BLOB)) FROM MyTable` for that record? (In UTF-8, `ö` is encoded as `C3 B6`.)

Comment: When you manually paste string into SQLite - it works with special characters. When using PHP to insert into SQlite I get the bad result. The Strings are pulled from a MySQL db and inserted into a SQlite. (This approach was used so that the data can be stored in the App docs and the app can function offline.)

Comment: @Magnus The question I think CL was trying to get at was that you need to verify what's in the database (i.e. either by running that SQL in your app, or run your app on the simulator and then actually open up the simulator's copy of the database from your Mac), so you can confirm whether the problem is reading the text from the database, or whether the root of the problem is earlier in the process, such as the storing of the string in the database or the retrieving it from the URL. Your question clearly implies the former, but the latter seems just as likely.

Comment: Side note: Create the sql statement like this: `const char *sqlStatement = "select * from Table";`. That's a plain old C-string.

Comment: Side note 2: Don't call `sqlite_column_text` twice. Call it once assigning the result to a `char *` variable. Then check the variable for `NULL`. It's much more efficient that getting the text twice.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Made mistake, assumed data from MySQL was UTF8. Turns out, although placed in a UTF8 column was not. Using utf8_encode in PHP fixed problem before insert into SQLite database.

Comment: @rmaddy I need your help. I am not able to get €¥ ãåāàáâäæ ėęēêèéë ìįíîïī õøōœòôöó ūùûüú special characters from sqlite database. I am using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)]` to fetch data.

Comment: @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ If you have a question, post a question.

Comment: @rmaddy  Thanks for your suggestion but it could become duplicate so I have not posted question. My issue was relevant to this post so I preferred to continue with comment. Any ways I get it solved.

Comment: @βhargavḯ, how you get it resolved?